# Why do I need to reopen a file to get its newest data?

Tags: c, linux

Here is my code to get the system information about the network device:

```
 FILE* f = fopen(filePath, "r");
 if(f == NULL)
 {
     perror("Error while open the file:");
     return -1;
 }
while(1)
{
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char s[20];
    fgets(s, 20, f);
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = '\0';
    printf(" %20s\r", s);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(2);
}
```

but the output just remain same, than I decided to reopen the file
every time I need to read it:

```
while(1)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while open the file:");
        return -1;
    }
    char s[20];
    fgets(s, 20, f);
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = '\0';
    char output[50];
    printf(" %20s\r", s);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(2);
}
and everything worked just fine, but I don't know why?
```

Comment: You should close whatever you open.

Comment: Thank you. But my point is, Is it possible to open a file just once and read from the start every time to get its lastest data? from the first code sample I pasted, it seems the data remains the same even when the file has updated.

Comment: What file you are reading? Is it a disk based file or something in a pseudo filesystem?

Comment: /sys/class/net/lo/statistics/tx_bytes     Is there any difference?

Comment: Yes, there will be difference. In case of /sys/class/net/lo/statistics/tx_bytes, you will need to check the kernel show function for this. I guess net/core/net-sysfs.c I guess. Sysfs files are different from normal disk based files. Seek works differently on them. And I am not sure there is an actual seek at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush the stream. Add the following before fseek.

```
fflush(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

After adding the fflush(f) it shows the updated content.

Working example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 FILE* f = fopen("/tmp/testfile", "r");
 if(f == NULL)
 {
     perror("Error while open the file:");
     return -1;
 }
 while(1)
 {
    fflush(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char s[20];
    fgets(s, 20, f);
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = '\0';
    printf(" %20s\r", s);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(2);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Keep modifying the file and save and observe the output of the sample program.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html

For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files,
       but not pipes or terminals), fflush() discards any buffered data that
       has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed
       by the application.

If you want to flush the stream on other OS, please check for the man pages for relevant OS.

Comment: In the first code sample, I have done it. But it still can not get update

Comment: I meant to add fflush(f); before fseek. I have tested after adding fflush(f) and it looks OK.

Comment: What OS?  Calling `fflush()` on an input stream is undefined behavior.  Per **7.21.5.2 The
`fflush`
function** of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  *If
`stream`
points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the
`fflush`
function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.*  The stream here is an *input* stream, thus calling `fflush` on it is undefined.

Comment: @Andrew Henle. according to the man pages for Linux, input stream on Linux can be flushed.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html

Answer (score 0):

In the line number 3 you have following coode.
FILE* f = fopen(filePath, "r");

Since it is inside the while(1) loop.
When each time it is getting called.
The latest file you are getting.

Where as in case one f is getting assigned only once.

Comment: You've basically just restated what the OP said in their question without giving any explanation of *why* this happens.